# Can remote LogMeIn Hamachi users access our local LAN?

Tags: vpn

Unknown to me, one of the kids has installed [LogMeIn Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/) on his PC so that he can access and play on his pal's Minecraft server, and vice versa.

However, my lack of fu when it comes to these types of services is leaving me feeling a little uncomfortable about him using this.

Is there anything I should be worried about here? For example, can his friends access our local LAN (which has a number of NAS boxes with unsecured shares) and get up to no good?

Or in other words can inbound VPN traffic from his friend's remote PC leak onto my local LAN. I did scour their docs but couldn't find anything conclusive about how this VPN application behaves.

One of the things I did was disable the *Client for Microsoft Networks* and *File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks* on the Hamachi NIC in Windows 7's Network Connections.

If someone knows this particular VPN application and its inherent dangers then your advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so, Hamachi is like its own NIC so as long as there isn't anything on the computer that is bridging your home network NIC to the Hamachi NIC it should be OK. However, I'm not very experienced with networking, especially Windows networking, so I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how exactly it's been set up, but in many cases yes.

At the very least they'll have access to anything that's shared on the local computer such as shared files or printers.

I always strongly advise against installing hamachi unless you really know what you're doing. Gaming is just about the worst thing to use it for.